# Using a pan gesture to select multiple tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, select, gesture, pan

I'm trying to implement a pan gesture on a table view to select multiple cells as they are panned over

The trouble I'm having is getting the tableview to scroll to the next cell when the user pans over the last visible cell in the table, or scroll to the previous cell when the user pans over the first visible cell

Currently when my pan reaches the last visible or first visible row in the table, it animates the next row in, but only for about the first 2 or 3 rows, and then it stops scrolling

After a bit of digging, it appears that it's due to the panGesture not being called, due to the users finger being stationery at the edge of the table.

How would I go about keeping the table scrolling, once the pan reaches the top or bottom edge of the table?

Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


    var lastSelectedCell = IndexPath()
    var gesturePan: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    var totalRows = 100


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //setup table gestures
        addGesturesToTable()

    }


}




extension MyView{

//MARK: - Tableview code
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return totalRows
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let lab = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    lab.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}


}


extension MyView{

//MARK: - Gesture code
func addGesturesToTable() {
    tableView.canCancelContentTouches = false
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    //add long press gesture to initiate pan
    let gestureLongPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(enablePan))
    gestureLongPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.25
    gestureLongPress.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    gestureLongPress.delegate = self
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureLongPress)

    //add pan gesture to select cells on drag
    gesturePan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(userPanned(_:)))
    gesturePan.isEnabled = false
    gesturePan.delegate = self
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gesturePan)
}



//LongPress gesture(to enable pan)
@objc func enablePan() {
    gesturePan.isEnabled = true
}


//Pan gesture
@objc func userPanned(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    //if starting to pan
    if panGesture.state == .began {
        tableView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        tableView?.isScrollEnabled = false


    //if pan position is changed
    }else if panGesture.state == .changed {

        //get indexPath at pan location
        let location: CGPoint = panGesture.location(in: tableView)
        if let indexPath: IndexPath = tableView?.indexPathForRow(at: location) {

            //if the index path.row is the first or last row of the data set
            if(indexPath.row >= totalRows - 1 || indexPath.row <= 0){
               print("data start/end reached")

            //otherwise
            }else{

                //get pan direction
                var direction: String!
                let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: tableView)
                if(velocity.y > 0){
                    direction = "Down"
                }else{
                    direction = "Up"
                }

                //if it's a new cell
                if indexPath != lastSelectedCell {

                    //select/deselect it
                    self.selectPannedCell(indexPath, selected: true, location: location, panDirection: direction)

                    //update last selected cell
                    lastSelectedCell = indexPath
                }
            }
        }

    //if pan gesture is ending
    }else if panGesture.state == .ended {

        //re-enable tableview interaction
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        //disable pan gesture
        panGesture.isEnabled = false
    }

}








//select/deselect the panned over cell
func selectPannedCell(_ indexPath: IndexPath, selected: Bool, location: CGPoint, panDirection: String) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {

        //if cell is already selected
        if cell.isSelected {

            //deselect row
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


            //if panning down
            if(panDirection == "Down"){

                //if it's the last cell
                if(indexPath >= tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.count)!-1]){

                    //scroll to the next cell after the last visible
                    let scrollToIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section:0)
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: scrollToIndex, at:
                        UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
                }

                //if panning up
            }else{

                //if it's the first cell
                if(indexPath <= tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]){

                    //scroll to the previous cell before first visible
                    let firstIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section:0)
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: firstIndex, at:
                        UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
                }
            }


        } else {


            //select row
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)

            //if panning down
            if(panDirection == "Down"){


                //if it's the last cell
                if(indexPath >= tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.count)!-1]){

                    //scroll to the next cell after the last visible
                    let lastIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section:0)
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndex, at:
                        UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)

                }

            }else{

                //if it's the first cell
                if(indexPath <= tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]){

                    //scroll to the previous cell before first visible
                    let firstIndex = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section:0)
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: firstIndex, at:
                        UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

                }
            }

        }

    }
}


}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There quick example how it can be implemented in your case, I think you can fit it for your needs easily.

```
var continueScrollToBottom: Bool = false
var continueScrollToTop: Bool = false

@objc func updatePanGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .changed:

        continueScrollToBottom = false
        continueScrollToTop = false

        // If you reach to the top make scroll constant
        // You can define there another condition which more suitable for you
        if sender.location(in: self.view).y < 200 {
            continueScrollToTop = true
            continueScrollToBottom = false
            self.startScrollToTop()
            return
        }

        // If you reach to the bottom make scroll constant
        // You can define there another condition which more suitable for you
        if sender.location(in: self.view).y > 350 {
            continueScrollToBottom = true
            continueScrollToTop = false
            self.startScrollToBottom()
            return
        }

    case .ended:
        continueScrollToBottom = false
        continueScrollToTop = false

    case .cancelled:
        continueScrollToBottom = false
        continueScrollToTop = false

    default:
        break
    }
}

func startScrollToBottom() {
    if continueScrollToBottom {
        if let last = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last, last.row+1 < countOfRows  {
            let showNext = IndexPath(row: last.row+1, section: last.section)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: showNext, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3) {
                self.startScrollToBottom()
            }
        }
    }
}

func startScrollToTop() {
    if continueScrollToTop {
        if let first = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first, first.row-1 > 0  {
            let showNext = IndexPath(row: first.row-1, section: first.section)
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: showNext, at: .top, animated: true)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3) {
                self.startScrollToTop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gkolunia, I solved it with a similar solution, but used a timer to trigger the continuous scroll

Comment: This is not working correctly. I want to know how to control the speed of scrolling and how to perform action(selecting/de-selecting) whenever new cell is visible

Comment: @jamiehancock , I want the code if you have solved it